# When collapse tree panel window in Internet Explorer 11 dont work

Tags: grid, rendercontrol

When collapse a tree panel in Internet Explorer the other panel does not shown correct and in other browser work fine. when the tree panel is hidden This causes the entire window to look wrong and can only be fixed by refreshing the page or expand another time tree panel is the property split is the one causing the error.

help only happen on IE.

Comment: can you post the html of the treepanel ? or the javascript used ? If JavaScript is being used to handle the treepanel , can you pls check if you are not getting any error in your console? Click F12 to go to developer console.

Comment: there is no error in the console.

Comment: can you pls add html snippet/screenshot. it is very difficult to visualize the problem.